# Vertical Alignment inside Blocs in flex mode §in Blogger)

Tags: flexbox, vertical-alignment, blogger

[2 blocks sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DR1B.jpg) in flex mode with 2 blocks side by side, block 1 with an image, block 2 with text in 2 parts, 1 part comment of the image and 1 part caption of the author of the image, how can I align part 1 on the top of the block and part 2 on the bottom

Comment: can you please provide the code of what have you tried?

Comment: actually, it seems to work with `#conteneur {width: 100%; margin: auto; padding: auto; display: flex; position: relative;}` and `#bottom {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}`.